# Composite WPF Problem -- View and Presenter Constructors Don't Run

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism

Please consider the VS 2008 .NET 3.5 SP 1 solution at this location:

http://www.theese.com/SolutionName.zip

This application uses Microsoft's Composite WPF (aka Prism) architecture. It is a very simple app that demonstrates a problem I'm having. I have one module with one view. That view gets mapped to the one and only region. For some reason, the view's constructor does not run (nor does the constructor of the associated presenter), though the module does load.

If the application were functioning as intended, you'd see a white screen with a red TextBlock in the middle containing the text "ModuleNameView". Instead, only a white screen appears. Can anybody see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your shell.xaml, you had a bug:

```
  cal:RegionManager.RegionName="x:Static local:RegionNames.MainRegion}"
```

should be

```
  cal:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static local:RegionNames.MainRegion}"
```

[notice the missing '{' at the beginning of your region name. That made it work for me.